# making transliterated words findable

Tags: discussion, hebrew, search

Tags are great, but often a particular word will be too specific to have a tag devoted to it, whereas you'll want people to be able to find the word on searching the site. If the word is English, no problem: people can search the site for it. If it's transliterated, though, then people searching might not choose the right transliteration scheme in constructing their search, and unless the site gets a Soundex-like system in place for searches, they won't find what they want.

One solution is to decide on a standard transliteration scheme to use site-wide. This was suggested by [AviD](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/459) in a comment at ["What is the common way to type in Hebrew for this site?"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13). However, I doubt that that's going to happen (as I mentioned there). Let's assume, for the sake of this question, that it's not going to happen.

What are other ways to make sure transliterated words can be found?

Comment: Can you give an example or two of particular words that are too specific for tags, but that we want people to be able to find by searching?

Comment: @Isaac, perhaps "קים ליה בדרבה מיניה" or "מנחת חביתין" or "נח נסתר".

Comment: Closely related later question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1404

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be a partial fix to synonymize a corresponding Hebrew tag for every English tag where applicable.

Comment: I do, too. As well as varying transliterations. But AFAICT I can't add a synonym unless someone's used it. I'm guessing a moderator can(?), but that's a lot of labor for the moderator(s), then.

Comment: A moderator can create any arbitrary synonyms, non-mods can only propose synonyms for existing tags (and then these need to be voted on). Yes, a bunch of work, but worth it IMO. The rest of us can help, by creating tags, synonmizing them, and upvoting the proposed ones.

Answer (score 1):

Google has actually figured out transliteration equivalents on its own. So when you search fro one word, it finds corresponding words and even highlights them. For example, it doesn't say "Shavuot" in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/milchigs-dairy-on-shavuos-when-is-the-proper-time), yet Google detected the equivalent word, "Shavuous":

http://goo.gl/OFN2B

Comment: To an extent, yes, but not completely: see http://goo.gl/Ov9PM.

Comment: Its based on what people actually use.

Comment: You can also try adding a '~' to search Google for equivalent terms, though I didn't check if it works for Jewish terms.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all questions and answers can have any relevant non-Latin-script (typically, Hebrew-script) words included in the original script, either by the post's author, or by someone editing it to add keywords, as at ["What's a good technique for a not-so-strong person to do [Ashkenazi] Hagbaha?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/3/revisions).

Comment: What you did there looks a lot like tagging and could be better accomplished by putting the Hebrew into the relevant tag's wiki, I think. Sticking in inline Hebrew may make more sense.

Comment: @Isaac: (1) Will a site search bring up results from tag wikis? (I just don't know.) (2) Like I said in the question, some things are too specific to have tags. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48418, where single-use tags were removed. (3) Re "Sticking in inline Hebrew may make more sense", yeah, good point. I agree.

Comment: (1) [Site search](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA) - no. Site-specific [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ajudaism.stackexchange.com+כשרות) - yes. (2) I see what you mean. I think I'd agree with this solution, inline, for those cases, but rely on the tag wiki approach elsewise. I suspect that Google searching happens a great deal more than site-searching.