# Capitalizing Translitirations

Tags: discussion, hebrew, transliteration

In relation to [making transliterated words findable](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/1913)

I have a habit of capitalizing when I transliterate from Hebrew. Is this something to be encouraged?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1770 & http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1417

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours seems to be a practice common to several users of this site, so I don't *remove* capitalization of transliterated terms when editing posts, but as far as I know it's nonstandard in English: the standard way of marking transliteration is with italics (or underlining).

Comment: Then, are we expected to italicize?

Comment: @JNF I don't think you are expected to do anything as long as it is clear what you are intending and it isn't SomEThiNG tOO HarD on the eyeS.