# Should we use Hebrew in tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, hebrew, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

There's been discussion of putting Hebrew into each post, whether for clarity or for SEO.  One way to do this (at least for SEO) is to add Hebrew tag synonyms.  Or if that's technically infeasible, we can at least use Hebrew in the tag descriptions.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

After seeing [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1405/1498), it seems that tag synonyms don't help SEO.  I still think it might be useful for clarity, but that's up to the community.

Comment: Question updated at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1598.

Answer (score 1):

Tag names (including synonyms) are (for now) restricted to the Latin (English) alphabet.

---

Waitasecond. [An MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135955) says we can have Hebrew tags. (But we don't. I just tried to add a Hebrew synonym.) I guess we just have to put in a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: Update: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1598.