# Can a Hebrew keypad be added on to the site?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [integrated hebrew virtual keyboard](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/integrated-hebrew-virtual-keyboard)

I think it would be beneficial if a Hebrew keypad was available for the site.

Comment: Duplicate of [](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/195/integrated-hebrew-virtual-keyboard)