# No Hebrew keyboard on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hebrew, user-interface

I notice that there's no [Hebrew keyboard](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1806/5) for posting questions on Meta.  Can we get that?

Comment: Checking on this, IIRC if we enable something on the main site, we pretty much also enable it on meta - will post back once I track it down.

Comment: @TimPost, thanks, but I just clicked the 'edit' link to see what would happen, and the Hebrew keyboard button did not appear.  Same thing when I clicked the 'Answer Your Question' button.

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't enabled on meta because the developers did a cursory look and saw that, well, Hebrew isn't really used here.

If you can provide me with some examples where it would have been beneficial to have it available here, I can certainly ask them to reexamine that decision. From what I understand there's a bit of a trick to getting it up and running properly, so they didn't enable it because there didn't seem to be a need.

Not putting a status on this yet - we'll definitely look at it if it makes sense, just didn't seem to at the time.

***Update***

This has now been completed. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for checking.  The primary use of Hebrew on meta is probably in our [glossary](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/581/472), but I don't know if that by itself is enough justification.