# How do you insert Hebrew text into a question or answer?

Tags: support, hebrew

I see a lot of questions an answers on Mi Yodeah containing Hebrew text.  Being skilled in MathJax for equations, I figured there was some underlying TeX-like way to do this.  But when I look at (by hitting "edit" then cancelling) the source, I see nothing of the sort, just the Hebrew letters themselves.

So how do I insert Hebrew letters into my question or answer or comment?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/195/7539

Comment: Also of interest: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88

Answer (score 2):

To type Hebrew in questions and answers, you can use the [integrated Hebrew keyboard](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1806/472), which was based on a userscript written by our very own @HodofHod.  This keyboard does not work for comments (though if you really need it for a comment, you can always start a post, type, cut/paste, and then cancel the post).

If you want to quote Hebrew text from somewhere else, you can just paste it in.