# Very-occasional Hebrew users might never truly learn the standard Hebrew keyboard layout; here are some possibly-better Hebrew-input alternatives

Tags: discussion, hebrew

Regular users of conversational Hebrew might type in Hebrew quite often. They might type emails, instant messages, and Facebook posts, all in Hebrew.

I type in Hebrew far less often. Still, I might occasionally type the odd word or phrase in Hebrew — for example, perhaps while composing a post on Mi Yodeya. Maybe once every month or two, if that.

---

I know I can configure my computer so that I can switch keyboard layouts on demand. This will let me easily switch between Hebrew and English keyboard layouts.

I type Hebrew so rarely that I suspect I may have forgotten everything I've known about the [standard Hebrew keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_keyboard), multiple times.

On-screen keyboards such as the [Mi Yodeya virtual Hebrew keyboard](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/integrated-hebrew-virtual-keyboard) are nice, but typing with my mouse is a bit fiddly.

Is there an easier, faster way? Perhaps an "input method editor" (IME) which will allow me to type Hebrew using my fingers, but with less of a learning curve required.

Comment: its very easy begin with כ ח and add one letter when you have the mastery

Comment: @kouty: Learning to touch-type in Hebrew requires regular practice. I don't practice often enough, and I don't want to practice regularly. So I might forget everything between every practice session.

Comment: To each their own :) ...you could also use [stickers](https://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-keywords=hebrew%20keyboard%20stickers&index=blended); I can't vouch for them, personally, but my friends have reported great success in using those.

Comment: @unforgettableid meta is for questions about using the site, not about Hebrew in general.  But we have a meta question about typing in Hebrew on this site, so I've migrated it and marked it as a dupe.  Feel free to move your answers here to the other question if they apply (I haven't read them carefully).

Comment: Odd -- a comment on the original post from Shokhet didn't move here in the migration but also isn't showing as deleted (so I can't undelete it).  Here it is, for context: "See judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/5323. || I learned to type using Windows' on-screen keyboard -- even if you don't want to learn to type, you can use an on-screen keyboard to orient your fingers. The Windows OSK shows the Hebrew characters on the keys together with the English characters, so if you can two-hand-type in English, it's not so hard to do that with Hebrew."

Comment: @Shokhet: Hmmm. The on-screen keyboard (or stickers) wouldn't truly require any memorization; yet they still might require me to spend time searching before every keystroke. In the end, if a person types in Hebrew seldom enough, I suspect that "Google Input Tools" or "Heblish" would remain easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Input Tools software. This software acts like a classical input method editor (IME). There's an [online version](https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/), a Windows version, an Android version, and a Chrome version. (I presume the Chrome version works on Windows, Mac OS, Chrome OS, and some other platforms.)

It's all freeware.

---

The online version offers lots of options:

- The typing option. You type a word in English, such as "mazal". It shows you a list of possible transliterations, ordered from most to least likely. (Google knows which Hebrew words are most common.) To accept the most-likely choice, you press the spacebar. To choose an alternative, you click on it or enter its number.
- The Google onscreen keyboard. It doesn't support glide writing.
- Handwriting recognition. This works well on cellphones and tablets. It's more awkward on computers, because drawing cursive Hebrew using a mouse is an awkward endeavor.

There's no vowel support.

---

The Android version appears to be divided into two parts:

- There's the [virtual keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), which supports tap typing, glide writing, and speech recognition. It has an optional "translate as you type" feature, which uses Google Translate.
- There's also the [handwriting recognizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime&hl=en), which is a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a product called "Heblish".

- The developer's "Web Heblish" product is free to use.

  - Basic use: You can see the [quickstart page](http://www.typeheblish.com/TryHeblish.htm) here, but that page doesn't really explain why some of the mappings have fallen where they've fallen. If you find that you use Heblish for more than two minutes a year, I highly recommend that you go through the [tutorial](http://www.typeheblish.com/index.htm) instead.
  - Advanced use: If you need to type vowels, see the [vowel tutorial](http://www.typeheblish.com/AdvHeblish.htm). If you need to change the direction of letters or words, see the [direction tutorial](http://www.typeheblish.com/AdvHeblishDirection.htm). Or you can see the [full reference card](http://www.typeheblish.com/MapHeblish.htm).
- The developer's ["Windows Heblish"](http://www.typeheblish.com/WinHeblishInstall.htm) product costs money to buy. I've never tried it.