# Examples and meanings of editing notes

Tags: discussion, support, editing

What does RLM stand for as an editing note, and what are others that are in use on the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used RLM as an edit summary to indicate that [I'm adding an RLM](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111) (right-to-left mark, usually by typing `&rlm;`).

Comment: Thanks. Now I wish I could remember what inspired my question, so I could go back and understand what happened in the edit that drew my curiosity.

Comment: @SethJ, welcs. Perhaps [one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/11936/revisions) of [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/11972/revisions)?

Comment: It was the first. Thanks!