# RTL support on MY

Tags: discussion, hebrew, formatting

The Stack Exchange network is gradually [planning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/300504) on moving to [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/). AFAICT CommonMark [doesn't support](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/explicit-rtl-indication-in-pure-markdown/286/22) any form of explicit RTL direction.

1. What is the current state of RTL on MY?
2. How will SE's plans affect MY?

Comment: islam.SE is another site that will be similarly affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the current state of RTL on MY?

[There is effectively no support for RTL on MY. There are workarounds, which all are inclusions of various characters via HTML entities.](/q/88/170)

> How will SE's plans affect MY?

It seems that they won't, since [CommonMark allows inclusion of HTML entities](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#entity-and-numeric-character-references).

Answer (score 0):

In case there *are* problems, here's something that might help.

I recently had a problem with RTL and `<q>` tags, which I was eventually able to solve myself:  [html - How to use HTML q-tag with RTL Hebrew alphabet - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128952/how-to-use-q-with-rtl-hebrew-alphabet).

The trick is to use the non-printing unicode `&#8207;` character, which switches the parsing into RTL mode.

Comment: Note that `&#8207;` is the same as `&rlm;`, which is documented in greater detail at [the page linked to from my answer here](/q/88/170).

Comment: @msh210, my fault for not actually reading your link (I carelessly interpreted "workarounds … various characters …" as meaning entities for the individual Hebrew characters).  Feel free to delete my answer.

Comment: @msh210, it's interesting that after more than a month Webmasters.SE couldn't answer my question, other than by saying it's not possible.  I guess I should have asked here (or meta).